# Eclipse does not keep auto assist settings

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

When trying to use code completion in **Eclipse C++**, I always get this error:

[image: error]

After clicking on *Restore Defaults*, the code completion works for one try, but the next try, I see the same error again. The error happens in both **Eclipse Mars** and **Eclipse Neon**. I've tried to delete the *.eclipse* folder in home, but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: Why did you suspect that deleting `~/.eclipse` could fix the problem?

Comment: Isn't that where eclipse stores its settings?